# Which is more succinct and why?

Tags: grammar

Version A:

> Foresters discovered that trees killed by acid rain had begun to die four years earlier, even though the trees had shown no signs of disease then.

Version B:

> Foresters discovered that trees killed by acid rain had begun to die four years earlier without any signs of diseases shown then.

To me, **B** is more succinct, although it does have that element of surprise created by "even though" in **A**.

My grammar book says that **A** is clearer, because in **B**,  it's not clear what the phrase "without any signs of disease" is meant to refer to.

Comment: What do you want, clearer or more distinct?

Comment: More succinct without loss of clarity would be: "Foresters discovered that trees killed by acid rain had begun to die four years earlier without showing any signs of dease."

Comment: Short but to the point

Comment: @Robusto, why showing not shown?

Comment: Because used that way the reference is clear, with respect to both subject and time.

Comment: @Robusto, so just "without any signs of disease" is not continuous and thus does agrees with the pluperfect?

Comment: You could drop the "showing" for brevity, but keeping it in helps the reader parse the sentence. Judgment call.

Comment: What do you mean "My grammar book says...?"

Comment: Why do you need an element of surprise in your writing?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a combination of Robusto's and Doeser's comments?

> Foresters discovered that trees killed by acid rain had begun to die four years earlier, without having shown any signs of disease.

[Ooops, sorry if the above is a comment, not an answer: I just discovered there is a distinction between them -- it's my first day on the site -- but am not certain what that distinction actually is.]

===============

Part B! Hi, Doeser. This is an addition to my answer at the suggestion of Sven Yargs.

"More succinct" simply means shorter, so you are correct that B is more succinct. But of course if a sentence is shorter but conveys less or incorrect information, that's not a good thing!

The problem with the second sentence is that the word "then" is just hanging out at the end of the sentence and could be read to refer to the time when the foresters discovered that trees had begun to die, as opposed to four years earlier.

My suggested rewrite is meant to attach the no-signs-of-disease thought to the correct time period.

Comment: Hello, Suzie NYC, and welcome to English Language & Usage. I upvoted your answer because I think it's better than either of the options that the poster offered in the original either/or presentation. However, it is only a partial answer at this point because it doesn't explain why it is more succinct (or better), which is a crucial aspect of the poster's question. Please consider explaining why your answer constitutes an improvement on the two original options. Thanks!

Comment: As for your confusion over answers and comments: Answers answer the question posed by the poster, and go in the answer box beneath a question; comments discuss aspects of the question—or provide a quick-hit answer without much documentation or detail—and go in comment boxes beneath a question or answer. At this point, you don't have sufficient reputation points on this site to leave comments anywhere but beneath your own questions and answers; however, that will change when you've accumulated 50 rep points here.